# C++ How to pass reference to function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class taking variables by reference. A function in the class needs to call another function that prints the object. The question arises when passing reference object from `process()` to `disp()`. Can I pass a reference from one function to another function? How to accomplish this using reference and what are best practices in such cases?

(I know one can take other approaches, such as using pointers or passing by value to class. But, I want to know solution with reference.)

```
class Abc
{
  double &a, &b;
public:

  Abc(double &var1, double &var2): a(var1), b(var2) {}

  void process()
  {
    //call disp()
    disp(a); //Question
  }

  void disp(double &var)
  {
    std::cout << var;
  }
};

int main()
{
  double x=2.2, y=10.5;
  Abc obj1(x,y);
  obj1.process(); //question
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Abc obj1(2.2,10.5);` is invalid as you take non const reference. (probably evil extension).

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't quite understand why is it invalid. Can you explain ?

Comment: Reference variables require a variable to be passed, since they usually modify their arguments. A literal (Such as 2.2) cannot be modified.

Comment: I am sure the compiler has a message for you.

Comment: You cant bind a temporary to a non-const reference, the C++ standard says so (although some compilers allow it)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: So you've updated the question so that the type has to be converted ... and you pass the converted as a non-const reference.  Did your compiler really not give you any messages?

Comment: _Can I pass a reference object to a function?_  Yes.  _How to accomplish this using reference...?_  The argument cannot be a temporary, nor can it be converted (which would make it a temporary), nor can it be a literal.  _What are best practices in such cases?_  Passing in a reference should not be captured-by-reference into a reference member variable, since that is the path to madness.

Comment: Reference member variables is one of those ideas that seem great when you've learned a little bit, but don't when you've learned a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I pass a reference object to a function?

Pedantic point: There is no such thing as a "reference object". References are not objects.

But yes, it is possible to pass a reference to a function.

> The question arises when passing reference object from `process()` to `disp()`

You already pass a reference there. That part of the program is correct.

---

You do have a problem here:

```
Abc::Abc(double&, double&);

float x=2.2, y=10.5 // anohter bug: probably intended to have a semicolon here
Abc obj1(x,y);
```

When object of one type (`float`) is bound to a reference of another type that is not related through inheritance (`double&`), the operand is converted to the target type (`double`). The result of the conversion is a temporary r-value. Non-const l-value references cannot be bound to r-values so therefore the program is ill-formed.

Even if the reference could be bound (for example, if you use a language extension that allows it, or if you used const references instead), the lifetime of the temporary would only extend for the lifetime of the reference variable which it was bound to, which is the argument of the constructor. After the constructor was finished, the member references would be referring to the temporary whose lifetime has already ended and therefore using those references would have undefined behaviour.

Simple solution: Use variables of same type as the reference: `double x=2.2, y=10.5`.

Comment: can you address the question how to pass reference from `process()` to `disp()`?

Comment: @dsf324 I already addressed it: `You already pass a reference there. That part of the program is correct.`